# Field $set aggregate results in error "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concatArrays' is not valid for storage"

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like the following

```js
{ 
  _id: '65b26e3b9fd1100007f05d0b',
  values: ['0123456789', '']
}
```

I tried the following operation on both mongo 4.4 and 5.0.24

```js
db.collection.updateOne(
  {
    _id: '65b26e3b9fd1100007f05d0b',
  },
  {
    $set: {
      'values': {
        $concatArrays: [
          { $slice: ['$values', 1] },
          { $slice: ['$values', {$add: [1, 1]}, { $size: '$values' } ] }
        ]
      },
    }
  }
);
```

On 4.4.18 I get the following error `The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concatArrays' in 'values.$concatArrays' is not valid for storage.` and on 5.0.24 it updates the value to

```js
{ 
  _id: '65b26e3b9fd1100007f05d0b',
  values: {
    $concatArrays: [
      { $slice: ['$values', 1] },
      { $slice: ['$values', {$add: [1, 1]}, { $size: '$values' } ] }
    ]
  }
}
```

So it seems that mongodb is interpreting my aggregate operator as if it was a value

Is there something I am missing or is this a bug in mongodb?

Comment: What is your goal? Remove the **last** element from the array? Or the second ?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit In this simplified case remove the last element but in reality it's to remove any element at a specified index, but I got my answer already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update statement in the sample uses a standard `$set` update that assigns the expression as a fixed value to the field. In order for MongoDB to evaluate the expression, you need to carry out an [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) by surrounding the `$set` with square brackets:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "65b26e3b9fd1100007f05d0b"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "values": {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $slice: [
              "$values",
              1
            ]
          },
          {
            $slice: [
              "$values",
              {
                $add: [
                  1,
                  1
                ]
              },
              {
                $size: "$values"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Above code leads to the following result:

```
{
  "_id": "65b26e3b9fd1100007f05d0b",
  "values": [
    "0123456789"
  ]
}
```

Please see this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4_ykoy-a2CL) to test.

Comment: Thanks.. I wish this information was more available in documentation with a big warning.. I spent 3 hours trying to understand what was going on, and I still would be looking without this answer